# Injecting code into Chrome pages

Tags: google-chrome-extension

When I inject a JavaScript file using

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["inject.js"]
    }
]
```

in `manifest.json`, it doesn't inject it to Chrome pages, like `chrome://extensions/`.

Is there any solution for it?

Comment: I don't know but I'd be surprised. This would be a security vulnerability (it could prevent the user from uninstalling the extension, for instance).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google doesn't allow extensions to work with certain URI like `chrome://extensions/` for security and development reasons. See *[Can extensions modify chrome:// URLs?](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/faq.html#faq-dev-15)*.

Answer (score 2):

While you can not modify other extensions you can modify other chrome://pages.  This process is called, Page Overriding.

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/override.html

An extension can replace any one of the following pages:

- **Bookmark Manager**: The page that appears when the user chooses the
  Bookmark Manager menu item from the wrench menu or, on Mac, the
  Bookmark Manager item from the Bookmarks menu. You can also get to
  this page by entering the URL *chrome://bookmarks*.
- **History**: The page
  that appears when the user chooses the History menu item from the
  Tools (wrench) menu or, on Mac, the Show Full History item from the
  History menu. You can also get to this page by entering the URL
  *chrome://history*.
- **New Tab**: The page that appears when the user
  creates a new tab or window. You can also get to this page by
  entering the URL *chrome://newtab*.